# What are the next meteorology breakthroughs?

Tags: meteorology, climate

It seems to me that not much attention is given to meteorology these days. I am wondering if this is because it is an almost "solved" science in terms of what could be possibly known and predicted. So, what are the next breakthroughs awaiting for meteorology and in general climate science?

Comment: Re "It seems to me that not much attention is given to meteorology these days" If weather forecasting is considered part of meteorology, the assertion does not seem to hold. For example, thanks to advances in supercomputing technology, MeteoSwiss has in recent years improved the resolution of COSMO forecasts to 1.1 km, allowing more detailed modelling of, and forecasting for, alpine micro climates. I *seem to recall* (no reference handy) that in the recent past modelling improvements were made to WRF pertaining to heavy rain events and wildfires.

Comment: Advances instead of breakthroughs might be a word to use.

Comment: This is an interesting question for some hours of fun discussion with scientists, but sadly not a good fit for Stack Exchange.  Weather forecasting on timescales from minutes to months is certainly one, there are also breakthroughs needed in climate science; I'm sure paleoclimatologists have their own wishlist, but there are many others.

Comment: by taking some of the information you use in your question the next breakthroughs will be more computing power and higher spatial resolution.

Comment: Echoing @Fred, the largest breakthrough in meteorology was the development of Earth observation satellites in the 1960s and 1970s, so much so that meteorology is divided between a before satellite era and a satellite era. The next big breakthrough was computer technology powerful enough to handle the new flood of information. Everything after that has been a minor advances.

Comment: ML is going to be interesting as well. Although part of me hopes it fails. Pretty recent example: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/group/autonomous-systems-group-robotics/articles/introducing-climax-the-first-foundation-model-for-weather-and-climate/